# Make seperate pandas data frames per header

Tags: python, csv, pandas, header

So I have a csv that contains data on a daily basis separated by a header.  Is there anyway I can make separate pandas dfs each time the program hits a header?

The data bascially looks like this

```
#dateinformation
data1, data2, data3
data4, data5, data6
#dateinformation
```

an example of the real csv is this

```
#7240320140101002301 131
21101400B   86    12B  110  325   25
10100000   200B    6B  110  325   77
20 95300 -9999   -27B  100-9999-9999
10 92500   820B  -39B   90  290
.....
#7240320140102002301
21101400B   86    14B  110  325   25
10100000   200B    2B  110  325   77
20 95300 -9999   -85B  100-9999-9999
10 92500   820B  -25B   90  290
```

I've already got the formatting of the actual data down fine.  I just need some help with how to separate out the different sets within the csv

Comment: would each of the fames contain the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(code below based on the header row starting with '#')

I suppose in theory you'd do this with read_table and chunksize but in practice I had trouble getting that to work very well on account of the different number of fields per row.  The following is fairly simple but I did have to resort to iterrows.

```
In [1435]: df_list = []
      ...: df = pd.DataFrame()
      ...: j = 0
      ...: foo = pd.read_csv('foo.txt',sep=' *',names=list('abcdef'))
      ...: for i, row in foo.ix[1:].iterrows():
      ...:     if row[0][0] == '#':
      ...:         df_list.append(df)
      ...:         df = pd.DataFrame()
      ...:     else:
      ...:         df = df.append(row)
      ...: df_list.append(df)

In [1436]: df_list[0]
Out[1436]: 
           a      b      c     d              e    f
1  21101400B     86    12B   110            325   25
2   10100000   200B     6B   110            325   77
3         20  95300  -9999  -27B  100-9999-9999  NaN
4         10  92500   820B  -39B             90  290

In [1437]: df_list[1]
Out[1437]: 
           a      b      c     d              e    f
6  21101400B     86    14B   110            325   25
7   10100000   200B     2B   110            325   77
8         20  95300  -9999  -85B  100-9999-9999  NaN
9         10  92500   820B  -25B             90  290
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work out for me!  However, my data set has 124,000 rows in it.  I'm relatively new to python and it seems like my IDE times out every time I run this, is this expected with this many rows or is something wrong with the code?

Comment: You could use ```nrows``` and ```skiprows``` to read it in smaller pieces.  ```chunksize``` is another way to do it but I had problems with it here, seemingly due to having different numbers of variables in different rows.

Comment: You might also replace ```sep``` with ```delim_whitespace=True``` as Bob did in his answer.  I believe that is more efficient and could matter if reading a large file.  You could also try using ```read_fwf``` or ```read_table``` instead of ```read_csv```.  I don't know if that would matter, but you could try it.  Sometimes with big files you just have to experiment and see what works best for your situation.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I actually just had to be patient, the program takes about 5 minutes to run which is not bad.  I will try these other things though.  Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that each 'frame' contains the same number of rows

First we read the file with pandas read_csv().  We leverage the comment parameter to omit each of your headers and read in just the data

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', comment='#', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df

    0           1   2   3   4   5
0   21101400B   86  12B 110 325 25
1   10100000    200B    6B  110 325 77
2   20  95300   -9999   -27B    100-9999-9999   NaN
3   10  92500   820B    -39B    90  290
4   21101400B   86  14B 110 325 25
5   10100000    200B    2B  110 325 77
6   20  95300   -9999   -85B    100-9999-9999   NaN
7   10  92500   820B    -25B    90  290
```

Then a for loop to parse and store each frame in a list.  I'm assuming number of rows = 4

```
frames = []
for begin in range(0,len(df),4): 
    frames.append(df[begin:begin+4])
frames[0]

    0           1   2   3   4   5
0   21101400B   86  12B 110 325 25
1   10100000    200B    6B  110 325 77
2   20  95300   -9999   -27B    100-9999-9999   NaN
3   10  92500   820B    -39B    90  290
```